# What do the `freq-offset-ppm` and `tick` columns in the output of `hwclock -c` mean?

Tags: time, hwclock

My system clock is about 2m ahead of real time. I'm about to fix it, but decided to run `hwclock -c` just for fun. My results:

```
hw-time      system-time         freq-offset-ppm   tick
1542485037   1542484930.078367
1542485047   1542484940.080521               215      2
1542485057   1542484950.080867               125      1
1542485067   1542484960.081214                95      1
1542485077   1542484970.081584                80      1
1542485087   1542484980.081927                71      1
1542485097   1542484990.082279                65      1
1542485107   1542485000.082645                61      1
1542485117   1542485010.082970                58      1
1542485127   1542485020.083356                55      1
1542485137   1542485030.083710                53      1
1542485147   1542485040.084061                52      1
1542485157   1542485050.084418                50      1
1542485167   1542485060.084741                49      0
1542485177   1542485070.085071                48      0
1542485187   1542485080.085395                47      0
1542485197   1542485090.085705                46      0
1542485207   1542485100.086030                45      0
1542485217   1542485110.086376                44      0
1542485227   1542485120.086734                44      0
1542485237   1542485130.087069                44      0
1542485247   1542485140.087428                43      0
1542485257   1542485150.087774                43      0
1542485267   1542485160.088111                42      0
1542485277   1542485170.088472                42      0
1542485287   1542485180.088818                42      0
1542485297   1542485190.089151                41      0
1542485307   1542485200.089468                41      0
1542485317   1542485210.089789                41      0
1542485327   1542485220.090126                41      0
1542485337   1542485230.090476                40      0
```

I understand the first two columns (Unix time for the hardware and system clocks), but what do the `freq-offset-ppm` and `tick` columns, both of which appear to decrease the longer I run `hwclock -c`, mean?

Google was unhelpful. Some of the pages that talk about `hwclock -c` have an output like the one above, but don't actually explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was basically some non-sense values. The option is now being removed:

https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/commit/92931ab28d2f9174b884b4373d6cdd1e0ef350d4